# Error Creating New Symfony 2.7 Project Using Symfony Installer

Tags: php, macos, symfony

I am trying to create a brand new Symfony 2.7 project and I'm following the installation instructions in the [Symfony Book](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#linux-and-mac-os-x-systems). I am running Mac OS 10.10.2. My php version is 5.4. When I try to create the new project with the following command:

```
$ symfony new myproject
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/symfony): failed to open stream: phar error: Cannot open temporary file for decompressing phar archive "/usr/local/bin/symfony" file "symfony" in /usr/local/bin/symfony on line 10

Warning: require(phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/symfony): failed to open stream: phar error: Cannot open temporary file for decompressing phar archive "/usr/local/bin/symfony" file "symfony" in /usr/local/bin/symfony on line 10
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/symfony' (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear') in /usr/local/bin/symfony on line 10

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/symfony' (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zend/share/pear') in /usr/local/bin/symfony on line 10
```

In the past I have created Symfony projects using composer and have had no issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where do you execute this command ? paste the path please

Comment: I execute the command from my home directory (~)

Answer (score 0):

I use these steps (under Linux) because I had the same errors:

in your **`public_html`** directory launch these commands to create a "*local*" symfony installer file (not `/usr/local/bin/symfony` like explain in https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer)

```
curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o symfony
chmod +x symfony
```

then launch the installer for symfony demo application with **`php`**

```
php symfony demo
```

or create a new symfony project

```
php symfony new project_name
```

then visit http://localhost/symfony_demo/web/config.php or http://localhost/project_name/web/config.php to configure the symfony project

**PS**: check the permission of file or directories